# Redirect only Skype audio to Bluetooth?

Tags: skype, bluetooth, headset

I have bluetooth headset Nokia BH-104 and bluetooth on my laptop.

How can i set, that all sound from skype I can listen on headset, and all other sounds (not from skype) i can listen from laptop?

Comment: you should mark your question as answered if the answer below worked.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to install an app called `pavucontrol` and use it to set the default device for Skype to that headset.